# How to split a DataFrame or Matrix into train and test sets on value not row?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a sparse matrix, G, whose values (the non-nan ones) need to be split into test/train sets. The test_train_split function from sklearn splits on rows but I want it to split on actual indices. Here's roughly what I'm trying to do

```
 1. test, train = split non-nan values in G (80/20-train/test)
 2. test_and_nan = combine test and nan sets
 3. G2 = G.copy()
 4. G2[ test_and_nan ] = 0 // initialize to 0 before imputing
 5. 
 6. do until norm(G2, frobenius) doesnt change much from last iteration
 7.     S,C = nmf(G2)
 8.     // use nmf decomposition to impute test_and_nan values
 9.     G2[ test_and_nan ] = (S*C)[ test_and_nan ]
10.
11. compute rmse( G[test] - G2[test] )
```

I want to use boolean masks to select the indices but I'm not sure how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the indices using a random vector with the size of your data (the number elements).
Something like this:

```
TRAIN_SIZE = 0.80
# Create boolean mask
# np.random creates a vector of random values between 0 and 1
# Those values are filtered to create a binary mask
msk = np.random.rand(len(data)) < TRAIN_SIZE

train = data[msk]  
test = data[~msk]  # inverse of boolean mask
```

Comment: This will split all the data, is it possible to only split the non-null values?

Comment: Yes. You can use the .indices attribute of your sparse matrix and split those values

Comment: I didn't realize there was an actual sparse matrix package. I meant sparse as in there are a lot of values codes as NaN. G is a DataFrame or ndarray.